# How to add exceptions in a checkstyle config

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have a Java project built with Gradle and using checkstyle with the default Google `checkstyle.xml` (coming from the project website).

Among others, it enforces a Javadoc for public methods. I want to keep this rule for normal code, but I don't want to write javadoc for my tests.

How can I add an exception to this rule, so that checkstyle ignores it for test files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done in two steps:

1. Specify a suppression file in `checkstyle.xml` by adding a [`SuppressionFilter`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter) module. More specifically, add the following code inside the "Checker" module:

   ```
   <module name="SuppressionFilter">
       <property name="file" value="config/checkstyle/suppressions.xml"/>
       <property name="optional" value="false"/>
   </module>
   ```

   where "config/checkstyle/suppressions.xml" is the path to the suppression file from the root of the project.
2. Create `suppressions.xml` as follows:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
       "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
       "http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">

   <suppressions>
       <suppress checks="JavadocMethod"
           files=".*Test.java"/>
   </suppressions>
   ```

   which tells the Checker to not apply the `JavadocMethod` rule for files with a name ending with `*Test.java`.

Note: in case the suppression file is not found or is not valid, you might encounter an error like:

> Unable to create Root Module: config {/path/to/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml}, classpath {null}.

Running the build with `$ gradle build --stacktrace` proved to be very useful for debugging this, in my case.